# Javascript form validation: custom error message

Tags: javascript, html

https://codepen.io/durja/pen/BPmmyR

I am trying to implement custom error messages for a form using the constraint api in html. Below is my code and I am facing an issue where after entering a wrong input and correcting it again, the validation message is still showing up. I am not sure what  I am missing. I even tried to check the validity using checkValidity() method which is returning false even though the input is of the correct pattern.

```
const fp = document.getElementById('quantity');
const ide = document.getElementById('ide_pref');

fp.addEventListener('input',e => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
   if(fp.validity.rangeOverflow) {
       fp.setCustomValidity('Custom message: greater than 100 not allowed.');
   }
});

ide.addEventListener('input',e => {
  console.log(e.target.value);
  console.log(ide.checkValidity());
  if(ide.validity.patternMismatch) {
    ide.setCustomValidity('enter exactly webstorm OR vscode');
  }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [HTMLSelectElement.setCustomValidity()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/setCustomValidity)

> The HTMLSelectElement.setCustomValidity() method sets the custom validity message for the selection element to the specified message. Use the empty string to indicate that the element does not have a custom validity error.

You're currently never resetting the custom validity message, so it remains `'Custom message: greater than 100 not allowed.'` (or the other message for the other element) forever whenever an input is invalid. Insert `else` statements (if there is no `rangeOverflow` or no `patternMismatch`) that call `setCustomValidity` with the empty string to clear the error messages, in case any exist when the button is clicked:

```js
const fp = document.getElementById('quantity');
const ide = document.getElementById('ide_pref');

fp.addEventListener('input', e => {
  if (fp.validity.rangeOverflow) {
    fp.setCustomValidity('Custom message: greater than 100 not allowed.');
  } else {
    fp.setCustomValidity('');
  }
});

ide.addEventListener('input', e => {
  if (ide.validity.patternMismatch) {
    ide.setCustomValidity('enter exactly webstorm OR vscode');
  } else {
    ide.setCustomValidity('');
  }
})
```

```css
.u {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.u:invalid {
  border: 2px solid orangered;
}

.u:valid {
  border: 2px solid greenyellow;
}

.btn {
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

:focus {
  outline-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="get">
  <div>
    <label for="ide_pref">Would you prefer webstorm or vscode?</label>
    <input required class="u" type="text" pattern="webstorm|vscode" id="ide_pref" name="ide_pref"><br>
    <label for="quantity">How many licences would you like?</label>
    <input required class="u" type="number" min="1" max="100" id="quantity" name="lic_quantity"><br>
    <button class="btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```